# vim key mapping with execute normal not working

Tags: vim

I want to highlight trailing space at the end of a line in vim. The following command works:

`:match Error /\v\s+\n/`

But I'm having trouble mapping this to a key:

`nnoremap <leader>w :execute "normal! :match Error " . '/\v\s+\n/' . "\<cr>"`

Vim responds with:

```
E114: Missing quote: "\
E15: Invalid expression: "normal! :match Error " . '/\v\s+\n/' . "\
```

**Update**:
Having just seen this: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Highlight_unwanted_spaces I've got the mapping working, by just writing:

`nnoremap <leader>w :match Error /\v\s+\n/<cr>`

Can anyone explaing what the problem is with the original `execute normal! ...` construct which prevents it from working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

---

### your mapping

I think it should be

**`nnoremap <leader>w :execute "normal! :match Error " . '/\v\s+\n/' . "\<lt>cr>"<cr>`**

**`:help <lt>`** I am not super aware of exactly why this is needed (once upon a time, my executes, too, were not working, as I had `\<esc>` and `\<cr>` in my `execute "normal! .."`s. Just know that in place or `<cr>`, you need to use `\<lt>cr>` for `<cr>` in this construct.

You also need the `<cr>` at the end to actually run the `:execute ".."<cr>` command.

---

### easier solution

Also, I think it's easier to just put

**`set listchars=trail:·`

`set list`**

in your vimrc, and then you will be able to see trailing white space.

---

Personally, I have **`set listchars=trail:·,tab:»\ ,extends:»`** in my vimrc.

and an easy regex search (`/\s\+$`) reveals the white space, which you can easily delete with <kbd>d</kbd><kbd>$</kbd> (**"delete 'till end"**). Then once you do that, you can press <kbd>n</kbd><kbd>.</kbd> to **"go to next"** then **"repeat"** the `d$`.

---

### cool tip

Once you highlight your search pattern, you can even <kbd>d</kbd><kbd>g</kbd><kbd>n</kbd> to "select next occurrence and delete it" in one go -- then you can just repeatedly press <kbd>.</kbd> until nothing happens ... `:help gn`. Also, mess around with <kbd>c</kbd><kbd>g</kbd><kbd>n</kbd>; it's pretty neat stuff.

---

Cheers.